# Is this more performant than findByViewId?

Tags: android, performance, android-custom-view, findviewbyid

Let's say I have a custom view:

```
<com.xx.xx.xx.CustomView
     android:id="@+id/customView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:onClick="doAction"/>
```

Then in my Activity I have:

```
public void doAction(View v) {
    if(customView == null) customView = (CustomView) v;
    ... do stuff
}
```

So as you can see, first time I click the view, I retrieve it and store it in an Activity field. Then I can use it anywhere. With this, I don't need to use findViewById.

I have to questions:

1. Is this more performant or is the same?
2. Is this a correct way to go?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you think findViewById is not performing well in your app? Please explain why you are trying to optimize.

Comment: The app has a lot of views in one activity, when you boot the phone, it consumes like 4MB... When opening the app and play with it a bit, it can go up to 60MB-80MB of RAM (I can see it in Running cause it uses the NotificationListenerService) and it doesn't go down. I am trying to rewrite the activity that has so many views and I am trying to be as performant as possible. But actually the question was for curiosity too.

Comment: If the layout is already inflated when you open the app, the view is stored somewhere, you're only storing an extra reference to it with findViewById, so I'm going to go with your method is not going to affect memory consumption.